# No matter how much I paint, the weight paint won't work

Tags: weight-painting

Yellow and green don't turn blue.[image]

[my blender file](https://cafeattach.naver.net/049118abbee9e03c13ff96af9879007ede8c72906d/20200611_255_cafefile/30035139_1591874010855_qrzTPR_blend/hime%2520hina4.blend?type=attachment)

Comment: Hello, seems to work fine here, either decrease the brush Weight to 0, or choose Blend > Subtract, with a Weight of 1

Comment: Even if I set the brush to zero, the yellow part doesn't change to blue. If I click the red part, it turns blue, but I want to make the yellow part blue.

Comment: it works fine for me, I hope someone will be able to help

Comment: The link to your blender file gives 403 error. Please upload somewhere accessible.